# How can I keep showing same background as scrolling down when gradient is used in CSS?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I like to add the effect of [CSS3 gradients](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)  and I applied it to my application as background color. My app shows a list of events and the length of a list is depends on the data.

My problem is that I cannot cover whole background with one gradient effect. As I scroll down, the end of one gradient comes and the new gradient starts. The image is as below.

[image]

I thought `height:100px` would work but it didn't.

What should I do? I use React and SCSS.

Search.js

```
export default class Search extends Component {
   constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data : ""
    }
    this.handleEvent = this.handleEvent.bind(this);
   }

   handleEvent(e){
    const start = document.getElementById("startDate").value;
    const end = document.getElementById("endDate").value;
    const city = document.getElementById("cityName").value;

    // get current time for the format valid format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ {example: 2020-08-01T14:00:00Z}
   var getTime = new Date();
   var time = "T" + ("0" + getTime.getHours()).slice(-2)+ ":" + ("0" + getTime.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + 
("0" + getTime.getSeconds()).slice(-2) + "Z";
   const url = `${baseUrl}&startDateTime=${start}${time}&endDateTime=${end}${time}&city=${city}${API_KEY}`
   console.log(url)

   axios.get(url)
      .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      console.log(response.data._embedded)
      this.setState({
        data: response.data._embedded
      })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert("error! Try again")
      })
   }
render(){
    let data = this.state.data.events;
    let events;
    if(data) {
     events = data.map(
        (obj) =>(
            <div className="result">
            <a href={obj.url}>
            <img src={obj.images[0].url} alt="img" height="300" width="300"/>
            <div key={obj.id}>{obj.name}</div></a>
            </div>
            )
            )
        }
    console.log(events)
    return(
        <div>
        <h1>Search Event</h1>
        <div className="form">
            <label for="startDate">From</label>
            <input type="date" id="startDate"/>
            <label for="endDate">To</label>
            <input type="date" id="endDate"/>
            <label for="cityName">City</label>
            <input type="text" id="cityName" />
            <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleEvent}>Search</button>
        </div>

        <div className="wrapper">
        {events}
        </div>
        </div>
        )
}
}
```

Search.scss

```
/** General **/
html {
 height: 100%;
 display: block;
 background: $lightBlue;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient($lightBlue, $blue); 
 background: -o-linear-gradient($lightBlue, $blue); 
 background: -moz-linear-gradient($lightBlue, $blue); 
 background: linear-gradient($lightBlue, $blue); 
 }

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: $pink;
}

a:hover {
 color: $darkPink;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My problem is that I cannot cover whole background with one gradient
>   effect. As I scroll down, the end of one gradient comes and the new
>   gradient starts.

You have to make use of :

```
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Here is the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Panther_007/aom7Lv0c/10/)

Comment: Glad to Help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try refactoring your SCSS slightly. Apply the background styling to the `<body>` tag.

Set `background-repeat: no-repeat;` to stop the gradient repeating, and `background-attachment: fixed;` to keep the background from scrolling.

```
html {
height: 100%;
display: block; 
}

body {
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background: $lightBlue;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient($lightBlue, $blue); 
background: -o-linear-gradient($lightBlue, $blue); 
background: -moz-linear-gradient($lightBlue, $blue); 
background: linear-gradient($lightBlue, $blue);
}

// Rest of your code....
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer with explanation!